# Choose where to save the image when you call save_frame() in MoviePy

Tags: python, django, moviepy

I'm using MoviePy to save a frame from an uploaded video (the specific function in MoviePy is `save_frame()` [source](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html#moviepy.video.VideoClip.ImageClip.save_frame)). This works successfully, however I want the image to save in my `media` folder (Django's conventional folder for saving uploaded files). At the moment it saves in the project root (where `manage.py` is). There doesn't seem to be a `settings` file so I'm not sure how to change this. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main idea to achieve that, maybe you have to make little adjustments:

```
# Your target directory
destination_dir = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'site_media', 'media', 'video_thumbs')

# Full path to file to open, I took the file path from filefield
origin_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, model.filefield.path)

# Get thumbnail
clip = VideoFileClip(origin_file)

# Save thumbnail on target directory
clip.save_frame(os.path.join(destination_dir, "thumbnail.jpg"), t=1.00)
```